# Inner join en MYSQL con PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo estas dos tablas en `Mysql`, como puedo conseguir con una `inner join` que me muestre todos los datos de ambas tablas?
La relación esta en el `idcurso`

```
Cursos
Idcurso
nombre
fecha
codigo

cursosprofesor
idcursosprofesor
idcurso
idusuario
```

muchas gracias!

Comment: Debes de subir el código que hayas intentado para poder ayudarte.

Comment: me parece que te faltan mas datos, por ejemplo otra tabla de donde salen los valores del `curso` y del `usuario` pues no estas guardando en la segunda tabla mas que sus llave foráneas, por lo que pareciera una relación de muchos a muchos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes revisar la documentación aquí: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html

Sí quieres mostrar aquellos datos que estén relacionados en la segunda tabla puedes utilizar `INNER JOIN`.

Para tú caso  podrías hacer algo así

```
SELECT Cursos.*, cursosprofesor.*
    FROM Cursos
    INNER JOIN cursosprofesor ON Cursos.Idcurso = cursosprofesor.idcurso;
```